NoResourceAvailableException for demo job WordCount when run Flink on Linux VM for the first time
Hi I just installed flink on my linux vm and it kept failing running the sample "wordcount"
I copied the same installation package to another machine and it worked well.
I'm wondering what should I do about my machine to make it work...
Thanks!!
The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 6233cc5efabf107d6fb17e686b45004f)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:1026)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1270)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$mainInternal$10(CliFrontend.java:1367)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.mainInternal(CliFrontend.java:1367)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1335)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 6233cc5efabf107d6fb17e686b45004f)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:170)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2293)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 6233cc5efabf107d6fb17e686b45004f)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:130)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$35(RestClusterClient.java:901)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:575)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:943)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:128)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:107)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:277)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:261)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:1636)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1084)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.markFailed(Execution.java:923)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionOperations.markFailed(DefaultExecutionOperations.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.handleTaskDeploymentFailure(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.lambda$assignAllResourcesAndRegisterProducedPartitions$2(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:811)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.PendingRequest.failRequest(PendingRequest.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.cancelPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.failPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:399)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(JobMaster.java:907)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$0(PekkoRpcActor.java:301)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(PekkoRpcActor.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.FencedPekkoRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedPekkoRpcActor.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.pekko.PekkoRpcActor.handleMessage(PekkoRpcActor.java:168)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:33)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
    at org.apache.pekko.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:29)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:547)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:545)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:229)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:590)
    at org.apache.pekko.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:280)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at org.apache.pekko.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.lambda$assignResource$4(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:226)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:607)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.

I tried to change the config file but actually it can run well without changing on another machine so I don't know
